# The number of permutations with a distance condition

Tags: permutations

How can I think about this question:

I have a string of As and Bs and I want the number of permutations such that the distance between two Bs is at least 2

```
for n = 3, the number of valid strings is 4
BAA
AAB
ABA
AAA

for n = 6,
AABAAB is valid 
BABAAA is not valid because the distance between the first two Bs is 1
AAAAAA is valid
BAAAAA is valid
ABAAAB is valid
```

Comment: In your first example (with $n=3$), I think you meant to say the number of valid permutations is $4$, not $3$.  (Incidentally, "permutation" is really not the right word here.  Just "string," or "word," would be better.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Each acceptable string of length $n\ge3$ either begins with an A followed by an acceptable string of length $n-1$, or with a BAA followed by an acceptable string of length $n-3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  let $C(n)$ be the number of acceptable strings of length $n$ that end with $B$  Let $D(n)$ be the number that end with $BA$  Let $E(n)$ be the number that end with $AA$.  Can you write coupled recurrences for each of these?  The answer you want is then $C(n)+D(n)+E(n)$ You might start with a spreadsheet to see what is happening.  It is [OEIS A164316](http://oeis.org/A164316)

Answer (score 0):

This might helps:

> Change $B$ to $ABA$, and calculate with dividing cases by the number of $ABA$.
>
> You might also have to consider the case when $B$ is in the end of the sequence.